# PHP Amazon S3 access private files through URL

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm using **AWS PHP** sdk to save images on S3. Files are saved privately. Then, I'm showing the image thumbnails using the S3 file url in my web application but since the files are private so the images are displayed as corrupt.

[image]

When the user clicks on the name of file, a modal is opened to show the file in larger size but file is displayed as corrupt there as well due to the same issue.

[image]

Now, I know that there are two ways to make this working. **1. Make the files public. 2. Generate pre-signed urls for files.** But I cannot go with any of these two options due to the requirements of my project.

My question is that is there any third way to resolve this issue?

Comment: facing same issue. +1 for that

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: Not exactly, I had to upload the images on S3 with public read access to make them accessible in browser.

Comment: go through with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359524/aws-s3-access-denied-when-getting-image-by-url

Comment: @SibtainNorain did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd highly advise against this, but you could create a script on your own server that pulls the image via the API, caches it and serves. You can then restrict access however you like without making the images public.

Example pass through script:

```
$headers = get_headers($realpath); // Real path being where ever the file really is

foreach($headers as $header) {
    header($header);
}
$filename = $version->getFilename();

// These lines if it's a download you want to do
// header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
// header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$filename}");

$file = fopen($realpath, 'r');
fpassthru($file);
fclose($file);
exit;
```

This will barely "touch the sides" and shouldn't delay the appearance of your files too much, but t's still going to take some resources and bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to access the files through a script on your server.  That script will do some kind of authentication to make sure the request is valid and you want them to see the file.  Then fetch the file from S3 using a valid IAM profile that can access the private files.  Output the file

Instead of requesting the file from S3 request it from
http://www.yourdomain.com/fetchimages.php?key=8498439834

Then here is some pseudocode in fetchimages.php

```
<?php

//if authorized to get this image

$key=$_GET['key'];
//validate key is the proper format

//get s3 url from a database based on the $key

//connect to s3 securely and read the file from s3

//output the file

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know you could try to make your S3 bucket a "web server" [like this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) but then you would probably "Make the files public".Then if you have some kind of logic to restrict the access you could create a [bucket policy](http://s3browser.com/working-with-amazon-s3-bucket-policies.php)