# how to access private objects from amazon s3 server in laravel

Tags: laravel, object, amazon-s3, filesystems

I have created a bucket on the amazon s3 and I kept some files in this bucket inside a folder. All the files are private and I am using laravel file system.

Please let me know how can I access the private files.

Thanks, Yogesh

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008841/amazon-s3-see-private-files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Amazon S3 see private files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008841/amazon-s3-see-private-files)

Answer (score 0):

AWS has a specific SDK that allows you to access and manipulate many of your services, including S3.

[AWS SDK for PHP](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/sdk-for-php/)

[Class for S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html)

Example for get S3 objects:

```
$s3Client = S3Client::factory([
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => 'YOUR-KEY',
        'secret' => 'YOUR-SECRET',
    ],
    'region' => 'YOUR-REGION-EX-sa-east-1'
]);

$s3Client->getObject(array(
    //see docs for params
));
```